# LayerGroup scope

Tags: javascript, scope, leaflet

If I create a LayerGroup in one Javascript function can I access it in another function in a different file? Or is the only way to declare it outside any function and make it global, i.e. it obeys same rules as any other JavaScript variable? I suppose I'm thinking that anthing referring to the map may be global by default as long as the map exists on the web page...

e.g.

```
fn1 {

   var myLayerGroup = L.layerGroup([marker1, marker2]);
   
    //....

}

fn2 {

   myLayerGroup.addLayer(marker3);

   //...

}
```

Grateful for help / advice - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just expand the scope of the variable to cover both the functions.

```
var myLayerGroup;

fn1 {

   myLayerGroup = L.layerGroup([marker1, marker2]);

}


fn2 {

   if (myLayerGroup)
      myLayerGroup.addLayer(marker3);
}
```

---

After the question being edited-

If you want to access the variable from another js file in the same web page, you can make it global by defining the variable global. The variable will automatically be global if you define it outside any function in one of the js files.

Comment: Thank you, you're right for the question as originally posed. I wasn't precise enough so I'm going to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myLayerGroup;

fn1 {
    myLayerGroup = L.layerGroup([marker1, marker2]);
    //....
}

fn2 {
    myLayerGroup.addLayer(marker3);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right for the question as originally posed. I wasn't precise enough so I'm going to edit it.